# torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 112.00 MiB

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pytorch

I have a big compute, 448gb of ram and 4 GPUS and I am executing this code:

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from transformers import pipeline

# Initialize the SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MistralUDFExample") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Initialize the pipeline outside the UDF
pipe = pipeline("text-generation", model="HuggingFaceH4/mistral-7b-sft-beta", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16, device_map="auto")

@pandas_udf(StringType())
def mistral_udf(texts: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    results = []
    for text in texts:
        messages = [
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": "You are a helpful assistant which only task is to analyze the text of emails sent to a customer service mailbox.  From this text you must extract a category.  No category labels will be provided. Email:",
            },
            {"role": "user", "content": text},
        ]
        prompt = pipe.tokenizer.apply_chat_template(messages, tokenize=False, add_generation_prompt=True)
        outputs = pipe(prompt, max_new_tokens=8, do_sample=True, temperature=0, top_k=50, top_p=0.95)
        generated_text = outputs[0]["generated_text"]
        results.append(generated_text)
    return pd.Series(results)

# Example usage
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'texts': ['Terrible experience shopping online?', 'When I called, the human on the other side was vert friendly']}))
output_df = input_df.withColumn('generated_text', mistral_udf(input_df['texts']))
output_df.show(truncate=False)
```

THe first time it works, but when I try to execute it a second time I get the out of memory exception.

1. How can I improve this code, so that it uses the loaded model and not load it every time? Or how can I fix the out of memory error.

> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate
> 112.00 MiB (GPU 1; 15.77 GiB total capacity; 3.16 GiB already allocated; 47.12 MiB free; 3.22 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If
> reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb
> to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and
> PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Comment: Amount of CPU memory doesn't matter at all -- when you're trying to run the model on your GPU, it's only VRAM that counts in this context. (This is a place where users of Apple's arm-based systems presently get to be smug -- having unified memory means that it all counts)

Comment: Your model "HuggingFaceH4/mistral-7b-sft-beta" would take around very close 16 GB. So I would suggest to use a smaller model. Or a bigger machine. Also make sure all of your 4 GPUs will get utilized when you the pipeline running.

https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/llama-7b-gpu-memory-requirement/34323/8